# How to use like clause in MySQL 5.0 Statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-like, mysql-5.0

I have a problem using 'like' clause in MySQL  5.0
I have written a stored procedure in MySQL 5.0
and calling the Stored Procedure from my Java Program 
the stored procedure below in the select statement i want to take the value of parameter departmentname for like clause please Help with this

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS upSelTests;
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE upSelTests
    (
    IN departmentname varchar(50),
    IN testDateFrom varchar(10),
    IN testDateTo varchar(10)
    )
    BEGIN
    declare testDateFrom1 varchar(30);
    select PatientID,LabNo,arriveddate,RecieptNo,patientname,referredby,ID from
    tblAcceptTest where STR_TO_DATE(arriveddate, '%d/%m/%Y')>=STR_TO_DATE(testDateFrom,
    '%d/%m/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE(arriveddate, '%d/%m/%Y') <= STR_TO_DATE(testDateTo, 
    '%d/%m/%Y') and Status = 0 and DeptName like '%departmentname%';
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please Help for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enclose `departmentname` in quotes, it becomes a character literal, and ceases to be a variable. Its value is ignored, and the literal `'%departmentname%'` is used instead.

The simplest solution is to use [`CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to add `'%'` as a prefix and a suffix, like this:

```
and DeptName LIKE CONCAT( '%', departmentname, '%')
```

If, for example, `departmentname` is set to `police`, the result becomes

```
and DeptName LIKE '%police%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Format:

```
SELECT field1, field2,...fieldN table_name1, table_name2...
WHERE field1 LIKE condition1 [AND [OR]] filed2 = 'somevalue'
```

E.g.:

```
SELECT * from tutorials_tbl 
 WHERE tutorial_author LIKE '%jay';
```

Comment: This is a verbatim quote from [this tutorial](http://www.academictutorials.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.asp). When you quote someone else's work like this, please give hyperlink references.