# How to query using LIKE clause in mysql using vb.net comparing to a varied string input?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, sql-like, clause

I've search and tried a lot of procedure but did not work.
CREATE PROCEDURE did not work, SET @variable is not acceptable and a couple more codes. This is my last "query" code that still didn't work.

```
qry = "select * from employeefile where empfname LIKE '%''" + input + "''%'"
```

empfname is a name of an employee from table employeefile that possibly consists of three words. The input could be the first word, second word, third word or the entire words.

when i tried to input any word within the name, the program will still prompt, "no records found." when i tried to change the query into

```
qry = "select * from employeefile where empfname LIKE '%existingname%'"
```

and my input is "existingname", the program runs just as i want it to.

This code is one of those that i seached but still didn't work.

[T-SQL and the WHERE LIKE %Parameter% clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237755/t-sql-and-the-where-like-parameter-clause)

[How to use like clause in MySQL 5.0 Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926724/how-to-use-like-clause-in-mysql-5-0-statement)

[T-SQL and the WHERE LIKE %Parameter% clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14237755/t-sql-and-the-where-like-parameter-clause)

The problem here is when i use a variable... i probably get the wrong way of using it into query. Please help me. I am new here by the way.

Comment: thanks guys for the tips. i got the answer. it turns out that i just overdid the single quote. it must be written this way:



qry = "select * from employeefile where empfname LIKE '%" + input + "%'"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got the answer. it turns out that i just overdid the single quote. it must be written this way:

```
qry = "select * from employeefile where empfname LIKE '%" + input + "%'"
```

Comment: Not using a parameter, therefore bad code, whether it works in some cases or not.

Comment: the above question is not using parameter; therefore, the answer should also not use parameter and the parameter thing will only be a suggestion. For starters, this could solve the LIKE clause problem then when everything turns okay, parameter will be the next issue. @jmcilhinney i hope you get what i mean

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding your question correctly:

```
Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM emplyeefile WHERE empfname LIKE '%' + @empfname + '%'", connection)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empfname", input)
```

or:

```
Dim command As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM emplyeefile WHERE empfname LIKE @empfname", connection)

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empfname", "%" & input & "%")
```

You have to concatenate the wildcards with the input text, either in your SQL code or your VB code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax: `LIKE '%blah%'`, but this code does not put the quotes outside the %s:  `LIKE '%''" + input + "''%'"`.